# multiple virtual-hosts on apache2.4 getting AH00959 : ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker (host) for 60s

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

We have multiple virtual hosts configured for Apache2.4 on Win 2012 server.
If one of the ports is raising `AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker (host) for 60s` will it block Apache from serving any requests being sent to other ports at the same time-slot?

Answer (score 1):

As long as each virtual host has its own ProxyPass (or RewriteRule with [P] flag) then no.

When Apache sends a request to a back-end server and it fails (normally because of a 500 error or the inability to get a connection at all), Apache marks that connection (called a worker), and only that connection, as down and you get the message you posted. Apache will then not use that connection for a certain length of time (default 60 seconds).

Any other connection as defined by any other ProxyPass directive should continue to work. I've not tried the situation where two vhosts have exactly the same ProxyPass directive and so I'm not sure if that creates 2 independent workers or not, but it would be easy to test.

This length of time Apache waits before retrying the connection is controlled by the "retry" option to the ProxyPass directive